# Individual positioning of x-axis labels in a polar highchart

Tags: javascript, css, charts, highcharts

I have a polar highchart with 12 categories. Since x-axis labels contain up to 4 lines, automatic label y-positioning is slightly off for the categories on the top and the bottom. It looks similar to [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/Rfaav/4/), but in my case, the labels overlap with the chart area, not with each other. So I need to subtract a few pixels from the y-coordinate of the labels on the top and add a few pixels for the category labels at the bottom.

I tried setting the offset parameter of the x-axis, but this shifts up or down all labels by the same amount:

```
xAxis: {
    offset: 20
}
```

I also tried adding a callback function to the formatter of the x-axis labels, but I just can't figure out how to adjust every category label position.

Comment: Have you tried to set [y postion](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels.y)? It should move labels. If this won't help, you can go through all labels (via `chart.series[0].data[0].dataLabel.attr( options );`) and set new options, where options can by like x, y, border, etc.

Comment: The y parameter you reference seems to take just one number for all labels. But I need to adjust labels individually. Didn't try `chart.series[0].data[0].dataLabel.attr( options );`, I use shorter labels instead which also fixes the problem.

Comment: Yes, that also makes chart more clear.

Answer (score 1):

this is a solution of highchart Heldesk

http://jsfiddle.net/crguqmsv/1/

```
function(chart){
    var len = chart.xAxis[0].ticks.length;

    $.each(chart.xAxis[0].ticks,function(i,tick){

        if(i>=0 && i<=90) {
            console.log(tick.label.attr({
                rotation:-45
            }));
        } 
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the position of the labels with the "x" and "y" options within the "labels" category under the axis definition.

```
labels: {
     x: 20,
     y: 10
}
```

In the above case, the labels will be 20px right and 10px down from their default position.

EDIT: I re-read the title, and Im sorry, this is for all the labels, not individually. My Bad.